# Usar FULL JOIN em MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Precisava de fazer uma query que me retorna-se numa linha os dados de um candidato mais os cursos a que se candidatou, sendo que estes dados se encontram numa tabela relacional 'tblcandidatoCurso'. Após alguma pesquisa tentei usar o FULL JOIN, mas aparece me sempre erro de sintase.

Segue a query que fiz

```
SELECT DISTINCT can.idCandidato, cur.idCurso, cur1.idCurso, cur2.idCurso
FROM
tblcandidatura AS can
INNER JOIN tblcandidatocurso AS cur ON cur.idCandidato = can.idCandidato
FULL JOIN tblcandidatocurso AS cur1 ON cur1.idCandidato = can.idCandidato
FULL JOIN tblcandidatocurso AS cur2 ON cur2.idCandidato = can.idCandidato
WHERE cur.ordem = 0
AND cur1. ordem = 1
AND cur2.ordem = 2
```

O objetivo era ter algo deste gênero:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: onde está a "tblcandidatura " ?

Comment: Se o relacionamento for entre as mesmas tabelas você faz no mesmo JOIN. No seu exemplo você esta criando 3 JOINS para  relacionar as mesmas tabelas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como o @fleuquer-lima disse nos comentários, você está criando 3 joins com a mesma tabela. Seu sql devia ser igual a imagem da pergunta, a **primeira** tabela **liga** com a **segunda** e a **segunda** tabela **liga** com a **terceira**.

```
SELECT can.idCandidato, cur.idCurso, cur1.idCurso, cur2.idCurso
FROM tblcandidatura AS can
JOIN tblcandidatocurso AS cancur ON cancur.idCandidato = can.idCandidato
JOIN tblcursos AS cur ON cur.idCurso = cancur.idCurso;
```